# Selecting an element with jQuery and changing it

Tags: jquery

I want to change an element on the html code of a website using the Chrome extension I designed

My problem is that the codes are like this :

```
<span>
    10<div>Number</div>
</span>
```

`<span>10<div>Number</div> </span>`

and I don't know how to select and change the number 10 with jQuery code ?

Comment: Is your jq tag right here? jq is a json parse tool.

Comment: My friend, I suspect that I should do this using jQuery codes

Comment: https://youmightnotneedjquery.com DOM apis have come a long way, and you really do not need jquery for this stuff anymore.

Comment: What way do you suggest? @MarianTheisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select a pure text node (which is what the '10' is) you need to use jQuery `contents()` function https://api.jquery.com/contents/#contents

```js
console.log($("span").contents().first().text());
// or, using plain JS to retrieve only the first node and it's text:
console.log($("span").contents()[0].textContent);
// change it to 11:
$("span").contents()[0].textContent = "11";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
    10<div>Number</div>
</span>
```

Note that `text()` and `textContent` will return the linefeed and spaces as well.